# create jquery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santosh_patnala/ecgAN/) I have a hard time to create a dropdown menus with the help of jquery.

```
$("a#SHOP").hover(function () {
            $("ul#test").fadeIn();
        }, function () {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                $("ul#test").fadeOut();
            }, 500);
        });
```

I am looking for submenus should be visible on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave the `#SHOP` element to hover the `#test` element, you trigger the fade out. One solution is to put add the trigger to the `#SHOP0` element, which is a parent of the submenu:

http://jsfiddle.net/bb3R2/

```
$("#SHOP0").hover(function () {
    $("#test").fadeIn();
}, function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("#test").fadeOut();
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be if you like to do this way:

```
$(".top-level li").hover(function () {
    $("ul#test", this).fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $("ul#test", this).delay(500).fadeOut();
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecgAN/1/)

What seemed to me that you want to show your submenus, this will work for other li elems also if they have child uls and also at the fadeout you need a half a second delay so you can use `.delay(500)` the way i suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You better user slideUp() / slideDown(), and your timeout is useless :

```
$("#SHOP0").hover(function () {
    $("ul#test").slideDown();
}, function () {
    $("ul#test").stop().slideUp();
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Akaryatrh/LLe77/1/

[Edit] Added stop() to avoid multiple animations chaining.